# How to solve System.Xml is missing error

Tags: c#, dll, dllimport

I converted a C# project which was created from Visual Studio 2010, to VS 2013. Now I am getting an error as follows,

Error   1

> The type 'System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

As I feel this is due to the missing of `System.Xml.dll`. How can I add it properly for the project.

Answer (score 5):

1. In the Visual Studio Solution Explorer, right-click "References". 
   2.Choose "Add Reference" and a dialog will show up.
2. On the left side of the dialog, select "Framework".
3. Find `System.Xml` in the results that shows up in the center, or you can search for it using the search bar.
4. Check the checkbox on the left of `System.Xml` and dismiss the dialog.

To double check:

Open the "References" branch of Solution Explorer and you will see `System.Xml`

Answer (score 0):

Try  adding System.XML.linq and System.XML to references

that will resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I could find a solution for this.

1. Right click on the References of the project
2. Select "Add References.."
3. Select the dll you want by putting a tick in front of the dll.
4. Click ok.

Then it will be imported